# How to RewriteRule without destroying relative path loading of source files?

Tags: .htaccess, url-routing

I have an ugly filesystem path on the server: `example.com/a/b/c/d/e/f/main.html`. For simplicity, I will use `example.com/httpdocs/main.html` in the body of this question.

I want that what the user sees is `example.com/easy-to-remember`. I will use `example.com/abc` in this question.

For reasons out of the question scope, I would like to do that with only the `.htaccess` file, not php-routing.

Let's start with the case that works:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Rewrite abc/ directory for loading of source material
    # Rewrite only if there is no actual file or directory that matches this request
    #   This can especially be useful for loading resources  
    #   because then the full paths won't be redirected if they are correct.
    # Note that RewriteRule never sees leading slashes
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^abc/(.*)$ httpdocs/$1 [NC,L]
```

With that, the user can open `example.com/abc/main.html` (expressive path) and is shown the page that is internally stored at `example.com/httpdocs/main.html` (ugly path). The user never sees the internal path; the url remains `/abc/main.html` in their browser.

Up to this point, everything works as intended. The CSS source files, specified in a relative path in `main.html` are still loaded correctly.
But maybe `main.html` is a very useless name. I'd rather have `example.com/abc` as a link, instead of `example.com/abc/main.html`. That'd be more expressive and would allow internal changes of the file extension without changing the links.

```
# Rewrite abc without trailing slash to main.html
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^abc$ httpdocs/main.html
    # PROBLEM: This turns the current url into "example.com/abc", so "./libs"
    # is now looked for in "example.com/libs" instead of "example.com/httpdocs/libs"
```

This rule still works for loading `main.html` without displaying that name in the url to the user.
*But the relative paths are now resolved wrongly*.

`/httpdocs/main.html` relies on `/httpdocs/libs/source.css`. In the first case, where we access `/abc/main.html`, the sources are loaded from `/abc/libs/source.css` and these loads are redirected to `/httpdocs/libs/source.css` so everything worked fine. In this second case where we access `/abc`, the css is loaded from `/libs/source.css` instead, omitting the `/httpdocs` directory - and that results in a 404, so the page is now not rendered correctly anymore (when accessed in this way).

The obvious solution would be to keep the first case, and if I really don't want to show the name `main.html` to the user, I could in addition add a rule that redirects `/abc/expressive-name` to `/abc/main.html` (or directly to `/httpdocs/main.html`).
But I am curious whether there are ways to achieve what I was trying to do without adding a second depth level (another slash something) to the url.

I want to keep the loading of the sources relative, so that if I ever have to move the whole filesystem to another subdomain or so, I can just copy the whole thing over. Without that constraint, I could simply make all loads absolute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you found out,you must keep the URL of the main file at the same level for the relative links to work. A simple way is to use the URL `/abc/` instead of `/abc`.

The difference is what the browser sees as the current directory or base URL. The base URL is the URL with everything removed after the last `/`. So with `/abc` the base URL is `/` while with `/abc/` the base URL is `/abc`.

So you can write:

```
RewriteRule ^abc/$ httpdocs/main.html
```

or you can omit the filename in the URL if you supply it with

```
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^abc(.*)$ httpdocs$1
DirectoryIndex main.html
```

The RewriteCond rules are just to make sure that the target is not an existing file or directory. As you know that the target doesn't exist, you can omit the rules.

If your main file is always named main.html, you can add `DirectoryIndex` just to the root directory (or a common ancestor). It would make the RewriteRules shorter, because you don't need separate RewriteRules for the directory and for the main file.

A get request to `/abc` needs an external redirect to `/abc/`, but apache will do that automatically if it detects that `/abc` is a directory.

A useful tool for external redirects is the program wget, it can display the redirects the server sends.

Comment: Thanks so much! What is the difference between the two approaches?

Comment: does that change answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

Copied from Jon Lin's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29899254/wrong-path-issues-on-rewriting-urls-with-querystrings/29899399)

> The extra slash in the URL changes the relative URL base. All your
>   links that are relative URLs in your content will now use the
>   incorrect base. You can fix this by either using absolute URL's
>   (starts with a `/`) or add a base in your page's header:

```
<base href="/" />
```